# Проверка hover в chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, hover

Подскажите пожалуйста как навесить "hover состояние" на объект в dev-tools и отредактировать его там же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выберите элемент, и в во вкладке стилей есть раздел фильтров, в нем можно выбрать псевдоклассы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]